# getting no resource identifier found error

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-support-library

I'm trying to compile [iven-feed-reader project](https://github.com/enricocid/iven-feed-reader), but in the Android manifest file I keep getting this error:

```
Error:(16) No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'
```

**Android manifest.xml:**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/Theme_iven" >
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"
        android:required="false" />
```

Usually i try to rebuild/clean project to fix this error but it's not working this time.

Below are the dependencies i'm using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: *i'm trying to compile link* no, you are not ... you had change it ... undo the changes and it will compile

Comment: I did change it little bit because the code was not for android studio, so i just used the import eclipse project wizard and changed the android version that's all changes i did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added this below line in your manifest tag ? 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Yeah it's there.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: I have added your code in my project but it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I will reinstall the android studio as my last resort.

Comment: I fixed the issue after testing it on android version 25, it seems the android dependancy has some issues with android version 24